# How to generate a number after a form is completed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form

Is there a way to generate a number for a form created on SharePoint?
For example, I want to have a person fill in a form with a lot of information and the I want their form to be numbered 1001 without having to input the number 1001 by myself.

Comment: Where want you to store this number ? in a custom field ?

Comment: It depends on what the specifications for the number are. Is it just to give uniqueness to the entries? Is it supposed to be the number of forms that have been submitted, thus far? Is `1001` a code to be referenced later (ie `1001` could be a New User form, and `1002` could be a policy refinement submission), etc. Can you give more information? **Additionally:** do you have access to InfoPath Designer? Some of these things are easier to do with InfoPath.